# Laravel y las tablas pivote

Tags: laravel

Tengo un formulario el cual podrán ver en la Imagen 1:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ese formulario se llama solicitudes, es un formulario donde se recibe solicitudes de autorización para poder reparar ciertos equipos médicos, después que se recibe esa solicitud nace una autorización para repararlos (pero esa es otra historia).

Por supuesto los equipos médicos pertenecen a un hospital y cada hospital tiene su propio inventario de equipos médicos.

Si ven el formulario de solicitudes hay dos botones "+" "-" ese botón de "+" al presionarlo me muestra una ventana modal que seria la imagen 2:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Allí podran observar todos los equipos que forman parte del hospital.

Ahora bien, si se dan cuenta en la ventana modal hay un campo "#" que es donde está el ID del equipo, está diseñado para que al presionar ese enlace el equipo del hospital que está en la ventana modal pase al formulario de solicitudes, como podrán ver en la Imagen 3:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora bien ¿Qué es lo que sucede en la vida real? Sucede que un hospital cuando se le daña un equipo, emite a un ente que los repara una "solicitud de servicio" que tiene todos los datos que pueden ver en el formulario de solicitudes, pero lo más importante es que esa solicitud tiene una lista de los equipos que se tiene que reparar.

Es decir "una solicitud puede tener uno o muchos equipos a reparar" y "uno o muchos equipos podrán estar en una o muchas solicitudes", ya que un equipo se puede reparar hoy y puede formar parte de la solicitud 0001 pero se puede dañar mañana y formar parte de la solicitud 0002.

Entonces he aquí una tabla pivote o tabla intercepción. La enorme duda que tengo es que esa tabla que pueden ver en la imagen 3 va a ir incrementando siempre y cuando un mismo centro pida en una misma solicitud reparar equipos que sean del mismo tipo, es decir un centro puede mandar a reparar 3 equipos de RX, es del mismo tipo, es decir, maquinas de RX.

Adicional les muestro:

Diagrama de base de datos, en rojo veran la tabla pivote:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Modelo llamado Equipo:

```
namespace dgmtm;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Equipo extends Model
{
  protected $table = 'equipos';

  public $timestamps = true;

  protected $fillable = [
    'centro_id',
    'servicio_id',
    'tipoequipo_id',
    'marca_equipo',
    'modelo_equipo',
    'serial_equipo',
    'bien_nacional',
    'equipo_garantia',
    'responsable_garantia',
    'duracion_garantia',
    'observaciones_equipo'
  ];

protected $guarded = ['id'];

public function centro()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('dgmtm\Centro');
}

public function servicio()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('dgmtm\Servicio');
}

public function solicitud()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('dgmtm\Solicitud');
}

public function tipoequipo()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('dgmtm\TipoEquipo');
}       
}
```

Modelo llamado Solicitud:

```
 namespace dgmtm;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Solicitud extends Model
{
protected $table = 'solicitudes';

public $timestamps = true;

protected $fillable = [
    'id',
    'autorizacion_id',
    'numero_solicitud',
    'fecha_solicitud',
    'centro_id',
    'responsable_emision',
    'jefe_servicio'
  ];

protected $guarded = [];

public function centro()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('dgmtm\Centro');
}

public function autorizacion()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('dgmtm\Autorizacion');
}

public function equipo()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('dgmtm\Equipo');
}        
}
```

Por ultimo el modelo llamado EquipoSolicitud (aqui aun no se como se representa las relaciones en Eloquent muchos a muchos no me queda muy claro):

```
namespace dgmtm;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

/**
 * Class EquipoSolicitud
 */
class EquipoSolicitud extends Model
{
protected $table = 'equipo_solicitud';

public $timestamps = true;

protected $fillable = [
    'solicitud_id',
    'equipo_id',
    'falla_reportada'
];

protected $guarded = ['id'];


}
```

Todaaaassss esa reglas de negocio ya están funcionando perfectamente pero ahora viene el tema de guardar en la base de datos.

¿Cómo hago para guardar en mi base de datos los datos de la tabla que se supone debe ir a la tabla intercepcon?

Comment: ¿Cómo tienes diseñada la base de datos? ¿Cómo están relacionadas las tablas que intervienen en este caso?

Comment: Hola amigo ya modifico el comentario para agregar imagenes de la relacion a nivel de la base de datos y voy a colocar imagenes de como tengo la relacion a nivel de eloquent.

Comment: Listo ya lo he mejorado, espero tus comentarios.

Answer (score 2):

En el Modelo `Solicitud`, la relación `Equipo` debe quedar así:

```
public function equipo()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('dgmtm\Equipo', 'equipo_solicitud')->withPivot('falla_reportada', 'otra_Columna_Uno', 'otra_Columna_Dos');
}
```

Para añadir equipos reportados a una solicitud con el texto del fallo reportado:

```
$solicitud=new Solicitud;
//No sé cuales son los nombres de los campos en el formulario...
//No sé cuales son los campos con autoincrement
$solicitud->autorizacion_id=Input::get('autorizacion_id');
$solicitud->numero_solicitud=Input::get('numero_solicitud');
$solicitud->fecha_solicitud=Input::get('fecha_solicitud');
$solicitud->centro_id=Input::get('centro_id');
$solicitud->responsable_emision=Input::get('responsable_emision');
$solicitud->jefe_servicio=Input::get('jefe_servicio');
$solicitud->save();

$falla="Este es el texto del fallo a reportar";
//Attach simple
$solicitud->equipos()->attach($equipoId, ['falla_reportada' => $falla]);
```

Y para obtener los datos:

```
$solicitud->equipo->pivot->falla_reportada;
```

Comment: Saludos Pedro por tu respuesta quiero hacerte unas preguntas: Realmente el campo falla_reportada tiene que ir es en la tabla EquipoSolicitud. colocando en la relacion la palabra withPivot, estoy diciendo que se va a guardar la falla reportada en la tabla pivote del modelo relacional?. los campos que dicen otra_columna que podrian ser?

Comment: Sí, claro, los datos de un fallo van en la tabla que se guardan los fallos. Y “otra_columna” pudes guardar lo que quieras, otra información adicional relacionada con la reparación... ¿fecha prevista de finalización? Por ejemplo

Comment: Pedro gracias por responder, es que el nivel de abstracción que veo me abruma...es decir, Laravel ya sabe que existe una tabla llamada EquipoSolicitud y es allí donde guardara el fallo? es que como en ningún lugar le estoy diciendo como se llama la tabla intermedia es por ello que me cuesta entenderlo...

Comment: He añadido el nombre de la tabla en la relación.

Comment: Hola Pedro...muchas gracias por toda tu ayuda, voy a probar y te cuento.

Comment: Hola Pedro...sabes que tengo una duda en esta parte: $solicitud->equipos()->attach($equipoId, ['falla_reportada' => $falla]);     Resulta que en mi tabla intercepcion yo necesito guardar tanto la solicitud_id como el equipo_id...para poder relacionar solicitud registrada con equipo afectado ademas de saber la falla de ese equipo...pero...como rayos guardo la solicitud tambien?

Comment: He modificado la respuesta. Ahora podrás ver cómo se guarda la `Solicitud`

Comment: Saludos Pedro...lo que quise decirte es al momento de guardar en la tabla pivote...si ves el modelo relacional veras que la tabla pivote dice: id, solicitus_id, equipo_id y falla_reportada. Cuando en Laravel se ejecuta es sentencia:  $solicitud->equipos()->attach($equipoId, ['falla_reportada' => $falla]); fijate que la sentencia es muy clara va a hacer un insert into (equipo_id, solicitud_id, falla_reportada) values (valor de equipo_id, valor de falla reportada, null) escribi null por que cuando ejecuto ese ultimo paso me dice...que no he pasado el valor de solicitud_id.

Comment: Ya lo he probado Pedro...ahora si ha funcionado...Quiero agradecerte por tu ayuda en esta etapa. Gracias.

Comment: https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Comment: Pedro esta vez te quiero preguntar otra cosa... hay relacion tablas pivote. Si has visto las fotos que puse al principio de todo esto, te darás cuenta que los equipos a reparar los he cargado de una ventana modal a un tabla en la solicitud, esa carga dinámica la he hecho con jquery...ahora fíjate ya sabiendo como cargar la tabla pivote, me viene el dilema de ¿como pasar los datos de la tabla que esta en la solicitud a mi controlador para cargarla?. Cuando yo le doy clic al botón verde que dice "guardar" de la solicitud eso hace un POST (PHP) a mi controlador para guardar.

Comment: pero...el asunto es que yo no se como (si es que se puede hacer) pasar los datos de la tabla a mi controlador con PHP...a ver...yo sabria como pasar esos datos usando Jquery..pero tu crees que hay otra forma de recorrer esa tabla en php y pasar los datos al controlador sin que intervenga jquery?

Comment: Si haces un post, tienes los datos en la variable `$request`o los puedes capturar con Input::get('nombre_input_formulario)

Comment: Hola Pedro...ese es el punto que no me queda claro como puedo enviar datos por POST de una tabla que tiene 'n' registros? normalmente cuando se hace POST de un formulario al servidor con laravel si los campos tienen el mismo nombre que los campos en el modelo todo funciona perfecto a traves del Request...pero en el caso de una tabla...como seria?

Comment: Bueno, no envias datos de la tabla sino de un firmulario. Todos los inputs que tuenen el mismo nombre los datos llegan en un array que hay que recorrer. Si el input se llama nombre los €atos llegan en nombre[0], nombre[1]…

Comment: Gracias por todas tus respuestas Pedro...